# What was TSR's Intruder comic/module about?

Tags: tsr

In the '90s, TSR produced several [comic books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSR,_Inc.#Comics). Many of these were based on some of the RPG settings TSR produced. The Comic/Module format often included either RPG stats for characters appearing in the comic, sometimes included campaign setting information for running the comic's setting, or sometimes the extra material was a miniature game.

There are promotions for the comics in the issues that includes a title called *[Intruders](http://www.mycomicshop.com/search2?TID=266091)*. It seems like it's advertised as a setting that attempts to bring many of TSR's settings together. As I have several issues promoting *Inturders*, I do not own a copy of any of the issues. Where can I find information about them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find the following [summary at Atomic Avenue](http://www.atomicavenue.com/atomic/TitleDetail.aspx?TitleID=8340):

> Dr. Eric Corbin suddenly found himself observing a horrific alien battle in the sky, while somewhere in the distance he could hear his wife desperately calling his name.
>
> Corbin’s body, plugged into a system of sensors and electrodes in a laboratory, is flatlining, so the attending doctors override Corbin’s orders and revive him, much to the relief of his wife.
>
> Corbin leads a project intended to study the human imagination. But the pure science aspect is being overshadowed by the government’s insistence that some military application be generated from his research. And after all, they are footing the bill. It is Corbin’s belief that he did not just imagine the battle he saw, but either was actually transported there or incredibly; his imagination was made reality. Hours later, alone with his wife, he thinks back to the world he saw and somehow disappears right out of his clothes to again find himself in an alien landscape.

The site lists nine issues as being for sale for a dollar each.

Comment: Also, if you decide to do your own search for "intruder" at Atomic Avenue, you should know that the first title listed is NSFW. ;)